Can remainder mod 2 be efficiently computed from addition and equality?
Suppose I have a programming language all of whose variables have natural number type. (So I cannot form higher-type objects, e.g., lists or trees, of natural numbers.) The only atomic commands I am allowed are addition and the only atomic test I am allowed is equality. Let's say the programming constructs are while loops, if-then-else statements, and recursive calls. I can use any natural number as a constant in my program.
This programming language is certainly Turing-complete, but it fails a complexity-theoretic notion of completeness; viz., it can't compute every PTIME relation in polynomial time. (In other words, we can simulate Turing machines, but not efficiently.) In particular, we cannot compute the binary remainder function $\mathrm{rem}(x,y)$, or even its ternary graph relation $\mathrm{rem}(x,y) = z$, in time polynomial in the total length of $x$, $y$, and $z$.
Question: in this model, can we compute parity, i.e., $\mathrm{rem}(x,2)$, in polynomial time?
Notes:

When I say "polynomial time" above, I mean with respect to the programming language, not time on a Turing machine.

This complexity-theoretic notion of completeness is called adequacy and is discussed by Nancy Lynch and Edward Blum, cf. this paper.



You're absolutely right. I did not mean to include subtraction in the list of operations. The resulting algebra $(\mathbb{N},0,1,+,=)$ is not adequate (Theorem 3.7 (a) ibid.). I have corrected my question.

Seems like you would have to compare x with each natural number in order. If you skip any, then you can't be sure that x didn't have that value. Thus the lower and upper bound is Θ(x) steps.

It's plausible, but I can't see how to make it watertight.

I really like this question! Here's a sketchy argument for a negative answer (as expected) which I think works but may need some details filled in:
Suppose our putative polytime parity-checking program $\pi$ uses constants $n_1,...,n_k$ and has runtime bound $p(\vert x\vert)$. Fix a "really large" $m$, and let $\vert y\vert=m$; the behavior of $\pi$ on input $y$ is determined by some set of terms of length $\le p(m)$ built from $+$, $n_1,...,n_k$, and $y$ itself.
Each such term $t$ has the form $$t(y)=a_0^ty+a_1^tn_1+...+a_k^tn_k$$ for some coefficients $a_i^t\le p(m)$ (the superscript not referring to exponentiation here!). Now as long as $m$ is sufficiently large, $y$ will be much greater than any of the related expressions $a_0+a_1^tn_1+...+a_k^tn_k$. Let $c$ be some odd number roughly comparable to $y$ (around $y\over 3$ let's say) and let $z=y+c$. Now $z$ and $y$ have different parities. However, for any two terms $t,s$ of the type above, since $c$ is much bigger than any of the $a_i^-$s and $n_i$s we will have $t(y)=s(y)\iff t(z)=s(z)$, so $\pi$ can't detect the difference between $y$ and $z$.
